Error: Root package not found at .. when importing self-made xmi file
I am working on creating a Python script to use self-created XMI files in Enterprise Architect. This should be done by means of a question catalogue. As I am still at the beginning, I am just trying to create a viewpoint with the questionnaire, which I then save as an XMI file and then import into EA. At best the viewpoint should appear in the project, but I keep getting the error - Error: Root package not found in : XMI.content/UML:Model/UML:Namespace.ownedElement/UML:Package. Does anyone have any idea what I need to change in the code?
Thanks in advance!
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from pathlib import Path
import uuid

# Funktion zum Erstellen des XMI-Dokuments für Enterprise Architect
def create_xmi(viewpoint_name):
    # Namespace-Definitionen
    ns = {
        'xmi': "http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1",
        'uml': "http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML"
    }
    ET.register_namespace("xmi", ns['xmi'])
    ET.register_namespace("uml", ns['uml'])

    # Erstellen des XMI-Baums
    xmi = ET.Element("xmi:XMI", {
        "xmlns:xmi": ns['xmi'],
        "xmlns:uml": ns['uml'],
        "xmi:version": "1.1"
    })
    documentation = ET.SubElement(xmi, "xmi:Documentation", {
        "xmi:Exporter": "Enterprise Architect",
        "xmi:ExporterVersion": "2.5"
    })

    # Modell erstellen
    model_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    model = ET.SubElement(xmi, "uml:Mod                           el", {
        "xmi:id": model_id,
        "name": "NaFv4_Model"
    })

    # Root-Package erstellen
    root_package_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    root_package = ET.SubElement(model, "packagedElement", {
        "xmi:type": "uml:Package",
        "xmi:id": root_package_id,
        "name": "RootPackage"
    })

    # Paket erstellen
    package_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    package = ET.SubElement(root_package, "packagedElement", {
        "xmi:type": "uml:Package",
        "xmi:id": package_id,
        "name": "ExamplePackage"
    })

    # Viewpoint erstellen
    viewpoint_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    viewpoint = ET.SubElement(package, "packagedElement", {
        "xmi:type": "uml:Class",
        "xmi:id": viewpoint_id,
        "name": viewpoint_name,
        "stereotype": "Viewpoint"
    })

    # Diagramm erstellen
    diagram_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    diagram = ET.SubElement(package, "ownedDiagram", {
        "xmi:type": "uml:Diagram",
        "xmi:id": diagram_id,
        "name": f"{viewpoint_name}_Diagram",
        "diagramType": "ClassDiagram"
    })

    # Diagramm-Ebene erstellen
    diagram_element = ET.SubElement(diagram, "element", {
        "subject": viewpoint_id,
        "presentation": "Class"
    })

    # Erstellen des Ordners, falls er nicht existiert
    output_dir = Path("output")
    output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    # Speichern der XMI-Datei im Ordner
    xmi_file_path = output_dir / f"{viewpoint_name}_viewpoint.xmi"
    tree = ET.ElementTree(xmi)
    tree.write(xmi_file_path, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
    print(f"XMI-Dokument erstellt: {xmi_file_path}")

# GUI erstellen
def create_gui():
    # GUI erstellen
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("NAFv4 Viewpoint erstellen")

    # Hintergrundbild laden
    background_image = Image.open("bundeswehr-corporate-design.jpg")
    # Größe des Bildes erhalten
    width, height = background_image.size

    # Hauptfenstergröße entsprechend der Bildgröße festlegen
    root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")

    # Hintergrundbild in Label einfügen
    background_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image)
    background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_photo)
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    # Label und Entry für den Viewpoint-Namen
    viewpoint_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Name des Viewpoints:")
    viewpoint_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
    viewpoint_entry = ttk.Entry(root)
    viewpoint_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

    # Button zum Erstellen des XMI-Dokuments
    create_xmi_button = ttk.Button(root, text="XMI erstellen",
                                   command=lambda: create_xmi(viewpoint_entry.get()))
    create_xmi_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()

# Programm starten
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_gui()


Are you sure creating an xmi file is the best solution for your problem? XMI is really complicated. Importing stuff is much easier using the API.

As Geert said. Have you tried to manually import the created file? Try exporting a simple model and compare it to what you created. Better: see above.
